# Control parameters of float environment in scrartcl

Tags: multicol

I would like to ask about control parameters on float environment in scrartcl class. I tried myself reading Koma-script manual but got confused. It's good but lack of examples. (IMO, they put a lot of cross-references that might be confused with someone new like me)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,%
columnsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{AAAAAAAAAA}
\date{}
%=======================================================
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\bfseries}
\setmainfont{TH Sarabun New}
\setsansfont{TH Sarabun New}
\setmonofont{TH Sarabun New}
%==================================================================
%RenewCommand Section
\newcommand{\keywordsEnglish}[1]{\textbf{keywords: } #1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
%======================================================================
\begin{document}    
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\vspace{0cm}\textbf{Abstract}}
\begin{abstract}
    This research presents.................
\end{abstract}
%==================================================================
\section{Intro}
\begin{multicols}{2}
%\lipsum[1] 
\begin{center}
    %   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionof{table}{ \ Data}
    \vspace{1mm}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        \toprule
        w/c ratios      &\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\scriptsize \textbf{$\beta$}}} \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-4}
        &0.55   &0.60   &0.65 \\
        \midrule
        {\scriptsize $D_{1}/D_{0}$ }    &0.301         &0.555           &0.876  \\
        {\scriptsize $D_{2}/D_{0}$ }   &0.603         &1.110             &1.751 \\
        {\scriptsize $D_{3}/D_{0}$ }   &1.205         &2.220           &3.503       \\
        \bottomrule
        \label{table:1}
    \end{tabular}
    %   \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \center
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
        \captionof{figure}{my caption of the figure 1}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:linear}
y = ax+b
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
QA.

\textbf{1.How can I manipulate figure/table heading and their caption?(i.e., fontsize, font type, beforeskip, afterskip, indentation, etc.)}

\textbf{2.How can I control equation's parameters? Especially making tag number to be Italic}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `multicol` environment from the package `multicol` doesn't support floats inside it.
- For changing `caption` parameters you need to use KOMA-Scripts syntax. It is described in its documentation in section *3.20. Floating Environments for Tables and Figures* on on pages 127 -- 142 (further pages deal with `\listof...`. Some basic settings are shown in MWE below.
- Changing appearance of equation numbers (to be italic) is not good idea. Better is to stick with default (deliberately selected) setting. However, if you like to have equation tags (numbers) composed like (section number.equation number), then you as solution can redefine `\theequation` command (see MWE below).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt,
               headings=normal,
               twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm,
            columnsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\small\sffamily}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theequation{\emph{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{amsmath, bm}        % <---
\usepackage{array, booktabs}    % <---
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\bfseries}
%\setmainfont{TH Sarabun New}
%\setsansfont{TH Sarabun New}
%\setmonofont{TH Sarabun New}
%==================================================================
%RenewCommand Section
\newcommand{\keywordsEnglish}[1]{\textbf{keywords: } #1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
%======================================================================


\title{AAAAAAAAAA}
\author{unknown }
\publishers{%
\itshape\small%
%\normalsize
\vspace{0.8cm}
\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{%
    This research presents \lipsum[66]
  }
}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\captionabove{Data}
\label{table:1}
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} c c c}
        \toprule
w/c \text{ ratios}      
            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{$\bm{\beta}$} \\
        \cmidrule(r){2-4}
            & 0.55  & 0.60  & 0.65      \\
        \midrule
D_{1}/D_{0} & 0.301 & 0.555 & 0.876     \\
D_{2}/D_{0} & 0.603 & 1.110 & 1.751     \\
D_{3}/D_{0} & 1.205 & 2.220 & 3.503     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
        \captionof{figure}{my caption of the figure 1}
        \label{fig1}
\end{table}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:linear}
y = ax+b
\end{equation}

QA:

\textbf{1.How can I manipulate figure/table heading and their caption?(i.e., fontsize, font type, beforeskip, afterskip, indentation, etc.)}

\textbf{2.How can I control equation's parameters? Especially making tag number to be Italic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is how I can find the correct keyword to redefind something like you used "\theequation" to adjust EQ number style. What if I need to make parenthesis italic too? What's keyword to control the parenthesis?

Comment: @kmmm, I will not do this. Changing parenthesis style is probably possible, but  probably also will have undesired side effect. I suggest you to ask new question about this your demand (please, only one problem per question).